# Open the OS default file explorer from eclipse plugin?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

I am writing an eclipse plugin, and one of the features I need is to open the OS native file explorer on a given folder. I couldn't find a solution with various searches...

Basically I have an IPath (or string) with a folder name. I need to open explorer.exe on Windows and whatever there is on Linux for that folder/directory.

Is there a way to do this?

Thanks,
Oren

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`Program`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fprogram%2FProgram.html) class of SWT. The `launch(String)` method in particular will do what you want:

> **Launches the operating system executable associated with the file** or URL (http:// or https://). If the file is an executable then the executable is launched. Note that a Display must already exist to guarantee that this method returns an appropriate result.

This will do:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    DirectoryDialog dialog = new DirectoryDialog(new Shell());

    String path = dialog.open();

    if(path != null)
    {
        Program.launch(path);
    }
}
```

Comment: Almost exactly what I wanted. I didn't need the dialog as I know the path I need to open. The Program.launch was what I needed. I haven't tested this on Linux yet, but I am hoping it works there just as well.

Comment: @OrenSarid I just added the dialog to have a testable code snippet. I've tried it here on Linux, but make sure it works with your distribution as well.